Lipogramas em Português
Um lipograma é um texto em que se evita deliberadamente o uso de uma ou mais letras específicas do alfabeto. Esse tipo de composição exige criatividade e habilidade linguística, uma vez que o autor precisa reformular ideias, substituindo palavras para respeitar a restrição de letras, sem comprometer a coerência da narrativa.
Esse estilo de escrita tem produções notáveis em várias línguas. Um dos exemplos mais conhecidos é o romance em inglês Gadsby, de Ernest Vincent Wright, que possui mais de 50.000 palavras sem a letra "e", a mais usada no idioma inglês. Outro famoso lipograma é o livro francês La Disparition, escrito por Georges Perec, também sem a letra "e" (ou "é" em francês). Em espanhol, temos El Secuestro de Jorge Luis Borges, que adota o mesmo desafio e mantém a ausência da letra "a".
Essas obras demonstram que é possível escrever narrativas extensas e coesas mesmo com uma restrição tão significativa. No entanto, surge a questão: existe um texto longo em português, um romance ou uma narrativa coesa, escrito em formato de lipograma, especialmente sem a letra "a", que é a letra mais frequente no português?
Se não existe, isso suscita uma interessante indagação: por que nenhum escritor ainda encarou esse desafio intelectual no contexto da língua portuguesa? A criação de um lipograma em português, especialmente sem a letra "a", exige um domínio profundo do idioma e uma capacidade extraordinária de adaptar expressões e frases para cumprir a restrição. Talvez seja uma proposta desafiadora o suficiente para inspirar algum autor ousado a explorar essa forma de escrita única.

Alguns links provavelmente relevantes: https://www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/22587/22587.PDF ;  https://www.google.de/books/edition/Op%C3%BAsculo_%C3%80_Contempla%C3%A7%C3%A3o/_W7xDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 ;  https://revista.classica.org.br/classica/article/view/889

Não encontrei nenhum lipograma de escritores consagrados no Brasil.
Contudo, acredito que produzir um texto nesse formato em português é muito complicado em razão da própria estrutura do idioma.
Por exemplo, em português, as vogais aparecem com altíssima frequência, especialmente "a", "e" e "o". Criar um texto que omita qualquer uma dessas letras exige evitar palavras extremamente comuns, como artigos, preposições, pronomes e verbos auxiliares:

"a": Aparece em artigos ("a", "as"), preposições ("para", "na") e terminações verbais comuns (cantar, falar).

"e": Está em plurais, pronomes pessoais ("ele", "eles"), conjunções ("e") e terminações verbais (ser, ter).

"o": Surge em pronomes ("o", "os"), artigos, preposições e terminações verbais.


Nesse sentido, o que encontrei de exercício criativo mais próximo do lipograma foi uma carta escrita por Guimarães Rosa em 1957 em que todas as palavras começam com a letra "c".
